# Apple Mail font is Helvetica Neue despite setting Arial as default font

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, font

My emails get sent with font type Helvetica Neue not matter what I try.
I selected Arial as default font in Apple Mail. Still my emails get sent with Helvetica Neue.

This is somewhat annoying because Windows users mostly do not have that font so they receive the mail and it gets 'Times New Roman' as font instead.

Anybody any ideas how to change it?

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue?